# Этимология слова «насаждения»

Tags: этимология, словообразование

Почему "насаждения", если деревья не насаживают на что-то, а сажают, посадят?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Схема образования слова: **насадить — насаждение.**

**Приставка НА** здесь обозначает действие, которое распространяется **на большое количество предметов.** То есть не просто посадить деревья, а посадить много деревьев.

Из словаря:

**НА** 2. Указывает на распространение действия на неопределённое множество предметов, накопление чего-л. в определённом (обычно большом) количестве в результате названного действия. Настроить (домов), натаскать (воды), набрать (ягод), насушить (грибов).

НАСАДИТЬ,  св. что и чего. Посадить какие-л. растения. Н. цветов, сирени.

НАСАЖДЕНИЕ; ср. 2. обычно мн.: **насаждения,**  Посаженные деревья, растения.